# How do I sort this printed vector without C++ library sort function?

Tags: c++, file, sorting, input, vector

After learning how to print a vector from an input file of numbers, I am now trying to learn how to sort those numbers using an algorithm and not the sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()) function. This is my sort algorithm:

```
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
```

And my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<int> arr;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("numbers.txt");

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file numbers." << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int i;
    int j;
    int n;
    int data;
    infile >> data;
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        arr.push_back(data);
        infile >> data;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                swap(arr[i], arr[j]);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) 
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " " << endl;
    }

}
```

Using this input file:

```
20
10
5
15
35
40
25
30
```

I believe my issue has to do with how i, n, & j are declared but cannot figure out anything past that. I hope the information provided is sufficient. I am VERY new to this. Thank you.

Comment: Where do people learn to use `while(!in.eof())`?

Comment: Well, you never assign a value to `n`, to start with :-) You don't need it in a separate variable anyway; you can use `arr.size()`. EDIT: Actually, no you can't just use `arr.size()`, since you do `n-1` (which could give a negative number, and `size()` returns an unsigned type).

Comment: You're comparing and swapping wrong array elements. Think how you need to compare to make sure the smallest element crawls all the way to the top.

Comment: Reading only the title, I recommend to use `std::set` and insert the elements one by one in it. This way you'll sort your elements without `std::sort`.

Comment: Right, I had actually put int n = arr.size(); earlier. Not sure why I took it out. Although it didn't sort, and I'm guessing it's now left to j and i, or just j if "int i;" can remain. EDIT: Noted.

Comment: @BaummitAugen from academics that don't code for a living.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize and increase (or set) the value of `n`.

Use

```
int n = 0;
while (!infile.eof()) {
  arr.push_back(data);
  infile >> data;
  n++;
}
```

or

```
int n = 0;
while (!infile.eof()) {
  arr.push_back(data);
  infile >> data;
}
n = arr.size();
```

I don't know how much you understand about sorting algorithms but this might be valuable: http://sorting.at/

Comment: Is that the only error?  Have you checked?

Comment: Thats causing the sorting errors you're having. As for other errors, no, I haven't checked, but from the looks of it, your algorithm seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Once `n` initialized to `arr.size()`, it works : (https://ideone.com/aNCwN6).